# How to enable Rating Setting using APIs

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, rating

Need to create a custom list with column as "Likes" which will hold the number of likes value. So there is a way using UI to enable this column setting. But how can this be done using REST API?
Looked for its documentation didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,Rest API may not support this.
We could find official rest demo on creating list and updating list.
[image]

List setting properties should be in SP.List.But I don't find any property about rate setting.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.splist?view=sharepoint-server

As a workaround,you could enable rate setting by powershell.

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/08/how-to-enable-rating-in-sharepoint-online-list-using-powershell.html